# Youtube API upload video java

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have an iOS app which uploads video directly to Youtube by using the below mediastream source:

```
MediaStreamSource ms = new MediaStreamSource(inputStream, VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT);
ms.setName(title);
    
newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);
        
VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads"), newEntry);
```

Recently it started failing and throwing an exception:

```
Throwable: No longer available
com.google.gdata.util.NoLongerAvailableException: No longer available
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>NoLongerAvailableException</code><internalReason>No longer available</internalReason></error></errors>

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:629)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:399)
```

Any idea what is gone wrong? We are passing the Developer Key and the user credentials